# Inequality in number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that:

(i)$5<5^{\frac{1}{2}}+5^{\frac{1}{3}}+5^{\frac{1}{4}}$

(ii)$8>8^{\frac{1}{2}}+8^{\frac{1}{3}}+8^{\frac{1}{4}}$

(iii)$n>n^{\frac{1}{2}}+n^{\frac{1}{3}}+n^{\frac{1}{4}}$ for all integer $n\geq9$

Can raising both sides to exponent $12$ help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(i) $5<2.2+1.7+1.4<5^{1/2}+5^{1/3}+5^{1/4}$.

(ii) $8>2.9+2+1.7>8^{1/2}+8^{1/3}+8^{1/4}$.

(iii) $n\ge3\sqrt n>n^{1/2}+n^{1/3}+n^{1/4}$ because $n \ge 9$.

Answer (score 5):

The last one is equivalent to showing 
$$1 > \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}+\frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}+\frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$
and 
$$n\geq 9 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{3}\geq \frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
$$n^2\geq 9^2 > 3^3 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{3}> \frac{1}{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$
$$n^3\geq 9^3 > 3^4 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{3}> \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$
and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For (ii) we have to prove that
$$6>2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[4]{8}$$
This can be written as
$$6-2\sqrt{2}>\sqrt[4]{8}$$
Raise to the power $4$
we have
$$3080>2112\sqrt{2}$$
Squaring we get
$$565312>0$$
For (i) we get by $$AM-GM$$
$$\frac{5^{1/2}+5^{1/3}+5^{1/4}}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{5^{13/12}}$$ so we have to Show that
$$3\sqrt[3]{5^{13/12}}>5$$ this is equivalent to $$27^{12}>5^{23}$$ and this is 
$$150094635296999121>11920928955078125$$