# prove that $5<\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[4]{5}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math, mental-arithmetic

> prove that $$5<\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[4]{5}$$

.A little use of calculator shows that  $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[4]{5}=5.44$.Thus the inequality is indeed true.

Generalising this result with $$f(x)=x-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[4]{x}<0$$ does not help as we see that $$8>\sqrt{8}+\sqrt[3]{8}+\sqrt[4]{8} \tag !$$

Repeated efforts of Bernoullis inequality have failed

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2796837/inequality-in-number-theory)? Found using Approach0.

Comment: So $\sqrt 5 > 2.2$, $5^{1/3}, 5^{1/4} > 1.4$ are quite easily to get without a calculator..

Comment: @Arctic Char, obviously this is the part the original poster had issues with. Maybe outline what you did or refer OP to resource(s) to calculate these estimates.

Comment: @ArcticChar please tell me how you thought of such values

Comment: First I find $2.2^2 < 5 < 2.3^2$ by direct calculation. That is we want $5^{1/4} > 1.4$. But that's true since $1.4^2 =1.96<  2$

Comment: $3(\sqrt5+\sqrt[3]5+\sqrt[4]5)=\sqrt{45}+\sqrt[3]{135}+\sqrt[4]{405}\gt\sqrt{36}+\sqrt[3]{125}+\sqrt[4]{256}=6+5+4=15=3\cdot5$

Comment: @BarryCipra wow! thats a nice observation! i wish the question was open i would have accepted!!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore, thanks. I agree, it's unfortunate the question was closed as a duplicate of a question that was closed as needing context (which I think your version provides). I have a fondness for these comparison questions that are "easily" answered by calculator; I like to see if they can be answered with calculations that can be checked by eye.

Comment: @BarryCipra hmm, is there any way i can reopen,say editing which will bring out your wonderful idea

Comment: There's a dedicated question at meta for requesting reopening, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today -- you could make your case there, but it may not be granted. Let me know if it is; I'll gladly convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By hand, you can compute :
$$2^2=4$$
$$1.7^3 =4.913$$
$$1.3^4=2.8561$$

So $$\sqrt{5} + \sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt[4]{5} > \sqrt{4} + \sqrt[3]{4.913} + \sqrt[4]{2.8561}= 2 + 1.7 + 1.3 = 5$$

Comment: How is that different from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2796870/42969 (which was already pointed to in the comments)?

Comment: This is not, I did not see the comment. @MartinR